# flutter tts is not working in real device

Tags: flutter, dart, text-to-speech

i am using flutter tts in my app to translate text to speech and it was working well in emulator but when i run my app in real device . It's not working .Please someone tell me what the hell is happening . why it is working well in emulator but not in real device . Also there is no exception occuring while running app in real device but still not playing.

Comment: We need more information than just that. Any debug logs? does the screen looks gray? do you have all the permissions in your manifest?

Comment: What have you tested so far?  Does the real device work when you test the tts demo text in settings?  Ask yourself what is different about the emulator and the real device.

Answer (score 0):

please try to run your flutter app on different android devices and test. some devices not supported text to speech and some gets supported. i have gone through it, so i tested it in different android devices.